# BackboneJS avoid re-rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone App with a large router. I use the Backbone Layout manager to load different layouts depending on what subpage I'm on. My problem is, that my top navigation gets rendered once again, each time the subpage gets rendered. So how can I avoid this?

My router:

```
routes: {
    '': 'index',
    'home': 'home',     
    ':name' : 'artistchannel',
    ':name/' : 'artistchannel',
    ':name/videoes': 'artist_videos',
    ':name/videoes/': 'artist_videos',
    ':name/videoes?w=:videoid' : 'artist_videos',
    ':name/releases': 'artist_discography',
    ':name/releases/': 'artist_discography',
    ':name/merchandise' : 'artist_merchandise',
    ':name/concerts': 'artist_concerts'
},

artistchannel: function (params) {
    artistController.initArtist(params.name);
},
artist_discography: function(params){
    artistController.initDiscography(params.name);
},
 and so on...
```

then I have a controller for each route (here artist and discography page):

```
ArtistController.prototype.initArtist = function(name) {
    this.artistModel = new ArtistModule.Model({slug: name});
    this.artistModel.fetch();
    this.artistModel.on('sync', function(){
        this.artistView = new ArtistModule.View({model: this.artistModel});
        App.useLayout('artistchannel', 'artistchannel').setViews({
            '.userMenu': this.acuserNav,
            '.artistChannelDiv': this.artistView
        }).render();
    }, this);
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
};

ArtistController.prototype.initDiscography = function(name) {
    this.artistdiscographyModel = new ArtistDiscographyModule.ArtistDiscographyModel({slug: name});
    this.artistdiscographyModel.fetch();
    this.artistdiscographyModel.on('sync', function() {
        this.artistDiscographyView = new ArtistDiscographyModule.View({model: this.artistdiscographyModel});
        App.useLayout('artistDiscography', 'artistDiscography').setViews({
            '.userMenu': this.acuserNav,
            '.releasesDiv' : this.artistDiscographyView
        }).render();
    }, this);
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
};
```

The same goes for concerts, merchandise etc.

All subpages (in this case artistchannel.html and artistDiscography.html) have the same menu in the HTML, which I want to avoid, so basically, its repeated code which looks like:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="{{name}}/releases">Releasepage</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="{{name}}/concerts">Concertpage</a>
   </li>
   etc. etc.
</ul>
```

So what I want that the topmenu not gets rerendered all the time. Is it possible to include all inside one single controller?

Answer (score 0):

Have a Layout & ShellView/MenuView. Don't append $el of every view to body, instead use a container for each specific view. One approach can be :

```
<body>
    <div id='menu'></div>
    <div id='content'></div>
</body>


new Backbone.Router.extend({
   initialize:function(){
       new MenuView({el:"#menu"}).render();  //this one creates menu
   },
   routes:{...},
   routeHandler:function(){
     new ArtistVideosView({el:'#content'}).render();
   }
});
```